# Birt viewer cannot load the report query

Tags: birt

When I am trying to run my BIRT viewer, the following error is displayed:

> Can not load the report query: 163. Errors occurred when generating the report document for the report element with ID 163. (Element ID:163)

But the same module is successfully giving result in report design in Eclipse. I am using JDBC connection. How do I solve this?

Comment: If you click on "XML Source" in eclipse, and search for id="163", is the element your database connection?  Do you have any parameters for specifying your database?  Did you upload your jdbc driver to the plugins/org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc/driver folder in the birt viewer?

Comment: @ruffp: please also remove "thanks" and the like when editing. Thanks!

Comment: I have flagged this question for closure.  The OP has not has not returned to provide information required (see comment) to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your jdbc driver to the plugins/org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc/driver folder.  That's usually what causes this.

It could also be a parameter that not getting set when you load the report.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message and my problem was in the query:

My Scripted DataSet was returning a **String** value mapped to a **Integer** column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log the SQL query text, set logging on the 
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement , which is responsible for 
preparing the SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the datasource for BIRT was not configured correctly. I needed to make sure the JNDI name matched what was in the config for my container.