# BIRT3.7.1, Maximo7.5, After XML Source changing, report cannot run properly

Tags: xml, birt, maximo

The problem is:
I develop report design file, everything is ok: sql query, parameters, datasource (I work with **maximo 7.5**, so, I develop reports in **BIRT 3.7.1** and use scripted data source, which create connection with the db2 database). First time I execute a developed report in maximo without errors. But after, f.e. I need to change a huge number of labes, I do this by modifying XML Source (just "find and replace") after uploading into maximo and testing of this report  I get error like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693310/birt-viewer-cannot-load-the-report-query), while birt display everything without any mistakes and errors.

I really cannot understand how modifying XML Source of report effects on queries, maximo, data etc.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Why can't you build where you don't need to change anything?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Good question, thanks. The requirments for my reports may change frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In db table I have a column which may store different values (within the meaning of dates, numbers, text). This column is an ALN type. So the main problem was with dates.  Date value in this field has a format "dd.mm.yyyy" (I forgot about it, shame on me) and in my report design I set data type as "date" and output format as "dd.mm.yyyy" because i thaught that i'll get values like "yyyy-mm-dd". So after that my report in maximo couldn't run properly. But i still cannot understand why BIRT did not show any errors.

Comment: Is this an answer to your question or addition to it?  If an addition you can edit the original question.

Comment: @JamesJenkins It is an answer, but I can't accept it right now.